# Convert string to numeric and keep leading zeros

Tags: input, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I am trying to convert a string into numeric and used the following code

select

```
 PROC SQL;
 CREATE TABLE WORK.CLAIM_HISTORY AS 
 SELECT input(cats(substr(SUBSTR(t1.LIABILITY_CTRT_ID,3),1,length(SUBSTR(t1.LIABILITY_CTRT_ID,3))-6),substr(t1.LIABILITY_CTRT_ID,13)),Z10.) AS GENERAL_INSURANCE_UOE_RK,
      t1.UNDERWRITING_DT
 FROM work.SIN t1
       LEFT JOIN work.custos_agregados_liab t2 ON (t1.CLAIM_NO = t2.CLAIM_NO)
 where t2.COVERAGE_CD <> '999';
 QUIT;
```

when for example, GENERAL_INSURANCE_UOE_RK wass 0223963 and when using the input functions, sas is deleting the leading zero and returning 223963. I would like to have exactly the same number, just formatted as number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Numbers by definition, do not have leading zero's. You can apply a Zn format to have it appear as if it has leading zeros though. What is the original type and format of the variable though?

Comment: And you haven't indicated what's wrong with your code....and I'm assuming it's the GENERAL_INSURANCE_UOE_RK field that's causing the issue?

Comment: yes, it's the GENERAL_INSURANCE_UOE_RK. The format was character and I want it to be numeric, the value should be 0223963 but when I put the 'input' is returning as 223963.

Comment: Why are you using `Z10.` as if it was in `INFORMAT`?  That should cause an error.

Comment: What value do you want if length of  `t1.LIABILITY_CTRT_ID` is less than 8? Or length of `t1.LIABILITY_CTRT_ID` is less than 13?

Answer (score 2):

Leading zeros have no meaning on a numeric value.  But you can attach the Z format to a numeric variable and have SAS display the value with leading zeros.

Note there is another error in your code as you are trying to use `Z10.` as an `INFORMAT`.  There is no `Z` informat.  Just use the normal numeric informat to convert the string into a number.

```
select
 input(cats(substr(SUBSTR(t1.LIABILITY_CTRT_ID,3),1,length(t1.LIABILITY_CTRT_ID)-8)
           ,substr(t1.LIABILITY_CTRT_ID,13)
           )
      ,32.) AS GENERAL_INSURANCE_UOE_RK format=Z10.
,t1.UNDERWRITING_DT
```